# Derivative of two independent varibles.

Tags: partial-derivative

Consider three quantities related by: 
$$y=f(t), x=g(t)$$
Then what is $(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})_t$? Is it simply that we cannot perform such an operation or is it $0$ or $\infty$? If it is one of the latter cases then what is: 
$(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})_t$ and is this equal to $[(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})_t]^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the chain rule:

$(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})=(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})(\frac{\partial t}{\partial x})={f'(t)\over g'(t)}$

and it is equal to $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})^{-1}$

Comment: In this how are you holding $t$ constant?

Comment: $t$ is not a constant and both $x$ and $y$ are depending on $t$ based on your description in the question. Am I not understanding correctly?

Comment: You are correct, however, when I perform the partial derivative I want to keep $t$ constant, so kind of like taking the partial derivative of a constant w.r.t a constant.

Comment: When you fix $t$, $f'(t)\over g'(t)$ becomes a constant as well then your partial derivative is just a straight line, is this what you meant?

Comment: I think I understood what you are asking now, the problem here is that $y$ is not a function of both $x$ and $t$, you could write $t=g^{-1}(x)$ and write $y=f(g^{-1}(x))$ and now there is no $t$ left and you will see what is happening.

Comment: No not really, let us say you have $y=y(x,t)$ I want to find $(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})_t$ but where $y$ has no $x$ dependency. You would nataully think that  $(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})_t=0$ but that rises the question of what is  $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})_t$

Comment: The problem is that you don't have $y(x,t)$, you only have $y(x)$ or $y(t)$ as $x$ and $t$ are not free variables.

Comment: If you meant $(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})\over{\partial t} $ that is a function of $t$ as well which is not necessarily $0$ and $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})\over{\partial t} $ is another function of $t$ and the product of the two is not one.